# code that i have to do it through LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

[image: Error after implementing the solution]

I have a code that i have to do it through LINQ

```
var airlineNameList = new List<string>();

foreach (DTTrip trip in contract_.Trips)
{
    foreach (DTFlight flight in trip.ListOfFlights)
    {
        airlineNameList.Add(flight.AirLineName);
    }
}
```

How can do it through LINQ.
Note: contract_ is the object of class.

Please Help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var resultList = contract_.Trips
      .Cast<DTTrip>()
      .SelectMany(trip => trip.ListOfFlights.Cast<DTFlight>())
      .Select(flight => flight.AirLineName)
      .ToList();
```

Don't you also need `Distinct`?

Comment: @Shivi, first of all you should kill `ArrayLists` :) And you should mention it in advance. Anyway I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond.. But i am Still geting some error..Please see the attachment..in mu above question

Answer (score 4):

```
var airlineNameList = contract_.Trips
                               .SelectMany(t => t.ListOfFlights)
                               .Select(f => f.AirLineName);
```

Comment: @Shivi - I don't understand what isn't working. Can you provide an Exception or something else to provide more detail?

Comment: He says that he uses `ArrayLists` so his enumerables are not strongly typed. `SelectMany` and others do not work on non-generic `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

```
var airlineNameList = (
    from trip in contract_.Trips
    from flight in trip.ListOfFlights
    select flight.AirLineName)
    .ToList();
```

The C# foreach does implicit casting for you (which is yuck), so perhaps you need this:

```
var airlineNameList = (
    from trip in contract_.Trips.Cast<DTTrip>()
    from flight in trip.ListOfFlights.Cast<DTFlight>()
    select flight.AirLineName)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I ma getting the error. "Could not implement the query pattern on ArrayList". SelectMany not found"..

Comment: @Shivi: If you have control over the class hierarchy, change the `Trips` and `ListOfFlights` properties to return strongly typed collections. This makes your code much more readable, because it saves you from doing the `Cast<T>()` calls and makes your code more safe. Another tip: Change the name of the `ListOfFlights` property to `Flights`. The `ListOf` prefix doesn't add any more information.